# How to deal with more than 100 callouts in a Trigger

Tags: trigger, batch, callout, future

I am creating an account Trigger with

the following  conditions:

IF: is not a batch request and is not a @future request
 we invoke a @future callout for each time the triggers fires.
ELSE:

we invoke a class that implements "queueable" which invokes a future callout with a List

So, sometimes there is an error that says that we are making more than 101 callouts, I believe that someone in this ORG where our APP is installed is updating the account object masivelly not using batch process.

I am not sure how to deal with that scenario.

Comment: It sounds to me like there are some red flags in the architecture of the code you're describing. There isn't much that I (or anyone else) can do if you don't provide the code that you're having trouble with, though. It would also be helpful to know what you're using an `@future` method for, and why you're trying to use `queuable` to try to 'chain' `@future` calls.

Comment: I agree, if you are having problems with someone batch updating, then that's a sign that your code isn't properly bulkified. You should always assume an update size of up to 200. Perhaps you can add a check if your queued job for the list size and do 2 future calls? Overall, though it sounds like you need to reevaluate the design choices made.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a Batch and when the trigger is fire you execute 90 batch per time, somethin like that

```
trigger SendDonorData on Contact (after insert, after update) {

        SendDonorBatch sdb = new SendDonorBatch(trigger.new);
        id batch = DataBase.executeBatch(sdb,90);
}
```